# Make a from element visible when a radio button is clicked

Tags: forms, javascript

I have a problem to make a date and a list element in a form in HTML invisible if the user selects one way, and visible if the user selects two. How can I write the JavaScript code for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to write JavaScript for that; if you are working in PHP, you can use [#states](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#states) on the form element.

Example: [form_example_states_form](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/form_example!form_example_states.inc/function/form_example_states_form/7).

```
  $form['high_school'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('High School Information'),

    // This #states rule says that the "high school" fieldset should only
    // be shown if the "student_type" form element is set to "High School".
    '#states' => array(
      'visible' => array(
        ':input[name="student_type"]' => array('value' => 'high_school'),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Comment: but how if i'm using radio button to select.Does the same code can be used in php??

Comment: Yes, as written in the doc link above, #states can be used with any form element

Comment: with the secret santa knowledge that `#states` is really emitting some simple jquery to show/hide stuff site since the action => condition array is just basically jquery selectors. A useful brief tutorial is at http://randyfay.com/states

Comment: tq very much @DavidThomas

Comment: tq also @tenken